# How to optimize this query with $and and $or

Tags: mongodb

Coming from SQL I have this search condition

```
WHERE (col1 LIKE "%foo%" OR col2 LIKE "%foo%") AND
      (col1 LIKE "%bar%" OR col2 LIKE "%bar%")
```

which I want to convert to MongoDB.

I came up wit this, hopefully semantically identical query:

```
{
  $and: [
    {
      $or: [
        { col1: /.*foo.*/ },
        { col2: /.*foo.*/ }
      ]
    },
    {
      $or: [
        { col1: /.*bar.*/ },
        { col2: /.*bar.*/ }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Is this the correct way or can it be improved?
Any suggestions about indexes (if they can be used at all)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's the correct way to implement that query for MongoDB.

If you want an index to fully assist the query, it needs to be a [compound index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#compound-indexes) that includes both fields, because MongoDB queries can only use one index per query.  So an index like this:

```
db.coll.ensureIndex({col1: 1, col2: 1})
```

You can confirm your query is using the index you expect by using [`explain()`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Explain).

Answer (score 0):

You have three problems here:

- `$and` is two evaluated queries
- `$or` is two evaluated queries
- None pre-fixed regex

`$and` does not use a multiple index plan, only a single index plan however $or does as such using a single compound index here will not help that much.

In fact no index will help since MongoDB cannot use indexes for none pre-prefixed regexs.

So actually adding any index at all would be useless to this query.

There is no way to optimise this query in it's current form.

Normally a good way of doing searches like this is to split out the words you are searching for into a subdocument of words that can be searched on directly and indexed. Take a look at: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Full+Text+Search+in+Mongo for examples.

When using this you would probably house one index on the array of words and that's it. MongoDB should be able to use that index for the entire query (twice over for the `$or`).

#### edit

Also an `$or` works different to how you have posted.

You don't need the `$and` and the two `$or`s. You only need one $or with a multi condition:

#### Edit again

I decided to take out the $or altogether. Note this uses the index unfriendly regex but still it is an interesting concept.

```
{ col1: /.*(foo|bar).*/ , col2: /.*(bar|foo).*/ }
```

If you want to use index friendly stuff then you will need to change the way your query works entirely as described above.

Comment: MongoDB _can_ use indexes for non-prefix regex queries, but it's not as efficient as all index values will be scanned and tested.  Also, I don't think this simplified query is the same because `{col1: 'foobar'}` matches the original query, but not this one.

Comment: Well if it has to scan all values in an index then the only real thing is the values possibly being memory loaded (if that index has been used recently otherwise page fault for values) 90% of the time an index won't really help here.

Comment: It depends on the size of your documents as if they're big then the index can still be of significant help as only the index needs to be loaded into memory.

Comment: @JohnnyHK The query has been amended, indeed *if* document is significant enough

Answer (score 0):

`and` and `or` queries are optimised in different ways. Quoting directly from [50 tips and tricks MongoDB](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920019893.do):

> Tip #27: AND-queries should match as little as possible as fast
>   as possible

and

> Tip #28: OR-queries should match as much as possible as soon
>   as possible

So depending on the complexity and flexibility of your actual queries, you should make `foo` and `bar` more generic, yet try to limit the results from both `$or` statements.

Hope it helps